# Method Overriding in Dart when the Return Type is "void"

Tags: dart, overriding, void, return-type

I anticipated a compile-time error when overriding a method in Dart without the *correct* (to my knowledge so far) return type. However, things seem to be different when the return type of the method is `void`:

```dart
abstract class AbstractClass {
  void methodDoesNotReallyReturnVoid();
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  // NO ERROR here!
  @override
  int methodDoesNotReallyReturnVoid() => 12;
}

void main() {
  print(ConcreteClass().methodDoesNotReallyReturnVoid()); // hm...?
}
```

The code above compiles without complaints and prints the integer as expected though I did not properly override that method like, for example, in Java.

May I know what is distinct about "void" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Ardent Coder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65373110/) cites specific details, but a short version is:

Can the `int methodDoesNotReallyReturnVoid()` override satisfy the *contract* of the base `void methodDoesNotReallyReturnVoid()` method?  Yes, because the returned value can simply be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, I had been looking for an answer of this kind, taking it from the design outlook. There's also a GitHub issue regarding this: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31968

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer after combining certain parts of the [Formal specification (Dart 2.2)](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf).

Firstly, there are conditions defined in the language specification for a method to be a correct override. In the scope of the confusion described in the question, here is the [section](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf#page=56) which matters:

> If *m* and *m'* are both methods or both setters: Let *F* be the function
> type of *m* except that the parameter type is the built-in class *Object*
> for each parameter of *m* which has the modifier covariant. Let *F'* be
> the function type of *m'*. *F* must then be a subtype of *F'*.

That means the return type under consideration **can be a subtype** as well. The following code snippet shall make it clear:

```dart
abstract class AbstractClass {
  num methodReturnsNum();
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  // No error here because int is a subtype of num
  @override
  int methodReturnsNum() => 12;
}

void main() {
  // Compiles and prints the integer.
  print(ConcreteClass().methodReturnsNum());
}
```

So going by the original problem, does it mean that `int` is a subtype of `void`? It was new to me, and [the answer](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf#page=185) is "Yes":

> Every type is a subtype of *Object*, every type is a subtype of **dynamic**,
> and every type is a subtype of **void**. Note that this implies that these
> types are equivalent according to the subtype relation.

Hence, the code in the question is similar to:

```dart
abstract class AbstractClass {
  Object methodReturnsObject();
}

class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
  // No error here because int is a subtype of Object
  @override
  int methodReturnsObject() => 12;
}

void main() {
  // Compiles and prints the integer.
  print(ConcreteClass().methodReturnsObject());
}
```

Addressing the element of surprise, a segment under [**Void Soundness**](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf#page=195) has a note:

> In particular, we could require that method overrides should never
> override return type *Object* by return type **void**, or parameter types in
> the opposite direction; parameterized types with type argument **void**
> could not be assigned to variables where the corresponding type
> argument is anything other than **void**, etc. etc. But this would be
> quite impractical. In particular, the need to either prevent a large
> number of type variables from ever having the value **void**, or
> preventing certain usages of values whose type is such a type
> variable, or whose type contains such a type variable, that would be
> severely constraining on a very large part of all Dart code. So we
> have chosen to help developers maintain this self-imposed discipline
> in simple and direct cases, and leave it to ad-hoc reasoning or
> separate tools to ensure that the indirect cases are covered as
> closely as needed in practice.